# Youtube video not embedding into Facebook - Error linting URL

Tags: facebook, video, youtube, embed, lint

I'm having trouble embedding my Youtube video into Facebook - when I paste the link onto my personal or page wall it starts loading but nothing comes up, and won't let me post just the hyperlink either.

I've tried using the Facebook Developer Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it says:

> "Errors that need to be fixed: An internal error occurred while
>   linting the URL"

It worked yesterday when I first uploaded the video on Youtube, but stopped working last night. And all of my other videos are embedding properly.

If anyone has any idea how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the link to the Youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXbxxYdGS1k

Thank you so much in advance!!

David

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution: unblock YouTube.

Detailed instructions: on the upper right corner of your Facebook page, click on the gear icon and select "Account Settings." Go to the left hand side of the page and click on "Blocking." Scroll down to the section titled "Block Apps" where you will see a list of the apps you have blocked. Find "YouTube" and click on the word "Unblock" next to it.

That's it, you're done. You will now be able to post YouTube links with thumbnails. No need to log out or do anything else.

I had exactly the same problem as reported here. The solution came to me just now when I realized I had swept through my Facebook settings a couple of weeks ago and pretty much locked everything down for privacy and denied apps the ability to do whatever it was a pop-up app approval box asked my permission to do.

As to why we all had the problem begin at roughly the same time, my guess is that, like me, you read a couple of stories about the new Facebook design when it was being rolled out. I recall that most of those stories, or ones related to it, had warnings about Facebook privacy settings and helpful tips on how users could control how much of their personal information is shared. Did those stories prompt you to take a look at your settings and possibly change them? That was what I did.

I hope this solution works for you.